# How can I trace the root cause of Neo4j 404 transaction errors?

Tags: neo4j

We are seeing a somewhat frequent occurrence of Neo4j transaction 404 errors where the transaction is being rolled back.

I've checked and tried to correlate the HTTP and Message logs

Aside from the HTTP and Message logs, are there other ways that we can try to find the root cause of the transaction 404 errors?  Are there other logs available?  What should we be looking for in the logs?

Comment: In your neo4j installation folder, go to `/logs/debug.log` and you should be able to find the problem.

Comment: I don't see the folder under the n4j installation.  Is there a configuration option that has to be set to turn this on?  (Version is 2.3.1)

Comment: I don't believe so. If you have the opportunity to upgrade to 3.0, however, I would recommend doing so; we had to do a lot of workarounds for transaction rollbacks due to deadlock conditions that became a non-issue with 3's improved deadlock handling. Also, unless you really need a long string of statements to be atomic, it's safer to just run each statement on the session than keep the transaction open; the network overhead isn't worth the increased risk of deadlock.

Comment: If don't mind sharing, what was the nature of your workarounds?  We are struggling with the same issue of deadlocks and so far, it has not been fruitful.

Comment: 1) If you can avoid executing more than one statement in a transaction, do so... transactions hanging open will lock any resources touched (in v2, I believe this is substantially improved in 3). 
2) Wrap your statement execute method (if you're using a language driver) or your HTTP request with an automatic sleep/retry... if you wait a second after a deadlock and retry, often it clears up.
3) Serialize your statements (have only one process execute statements, while other threads/processes pass them into a queue and deal with the results). Slow, but effective.